# aws usage plan quota based on per user

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

The thing I am trying to achieve is with the help of usage plan quota, I want to restrict the user API hit.

For Example:-
Usage plan quota for API is 5 request per day.

1. User1 - hit the API for more than 5 times then it gives him limit exceeds the error
2. User2 - hit the API for more than 5 times and the same.

I am not able to achieve this behaviour, I am able to limit the API request for all user not for a particular user.

Tried to search the web not able to find any article. Another way to achieve the above task are welcomed.

**Note** :

Dont provide any article from AWS doc.

If you can explain with simple example you are welcome or else dont post any AWS Doc link in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending my 2 days there are lot of things which I learned along with AWS for the above answer

1. So if you are a beginner like me whose AWS starting phase consists of API gateway and dynamodb, would like to inform you that almost every button you see in AWS management panel like creating usage plan, creating API key, associating API Key with your plan all these things can be done via AWS SDK and AWS CLI.
2. AWS SDK is not only used to write a query to extract data from dynamodb or to read file from AWS S3.
3. Solution for above scenario -

- When the user is created we create API key specific for that user using AWS APIGateway SDK method name `CreateApiKey`,you wont find this method in APIGateway2.
- Once the API Key is created we assign to our usage plan using this method `CreateUsagePlanKey`
- By this way we can create multiple API Key per user, how to store and related it solely depend on your logic

Answer (score 1):

You can implement throttling, quota limits and usage plans using AWS API Gateway in conjunction with API keys. Have a look at [Creating and using usage plans with API keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html) in the AWS documentation.

Comment: This is definitely the approach to go for if you want to use native API Gateway functionality.

Comment: @DennisTraub can you explain in more detail, or provide an example ..I have read that article but may be I am not able to understand it completely as I have just started using AWS and working on backend services. Any help will be great

Comment: Its not just @DennisTraub but any one can explain me

Comment: Have you followed the guides referenced from that article? What exactly isn’t working?

Comment: @DennisTraub Ya that article is nothing but the basic thing on creation and used of usage plan. It seems like you have not understood my question and second thing stop posting AWS Doc in answer if you cant explain thats fine because people come to stackoverflow to get proper explanation  for there issue and technical knowledge not to read docs which they have already read and are still confused.

Comment: I’m sorry that I wasn’t able to answer your question. Maybe someone else can help.